# ListView adapter: caching views

Tags: android

When implementing an adapter for a ListViev, it is necessary to implement `getView()` method.

I cached the views created in `getView()`, and returned the cached view when `getView()` called again for the same position.

```
@Override
View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View currentView = getCachedView(position);
    if (currentView == null) {
        currentView = createView();
        cacheView(currentView, position);
    }
    return currentView;
}
```

The reason to do this is to make the `ListView` scroll faster because the adapter doesn't have to create the view again for every time `getView()` is called.

I know that this goes against the purpose of having an adapter, but my `ListView` only has few items, and keeping all item views in memory is not a big overhead. On the other hand, creating a view is costly since the layout of an item is somewhat complex and has bitmaps on it.

Also, I know that I can reuse `convertView`, but caching the already created view is much simpler and there is no need to render the bitmaps again on the `convertView`.

Is there anything wrong in this approach, in addition to the waste of memory to keep all list item views in memory?

Comment: Should't you be using `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @SaranSankaran Isn't RecyclerView `for providing a limited window into a large data set`? In my case, the data set is not large and I can easily keep that in memory.

Comment: `RecyclerView` basically caches the View and uses it again to display the next content when a user scrolls. So basically the caching which you are handling manually is handled by the `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

I tried caching the views and seems like it causes various random issues like click events on cached views not firing properly, etc.

I don't know what is the cause for these issues and whether they can be fixed someway, so I decided re-use `convertView` instead of caching views.